# Android OnItemClickListener not trigger when I use Handler to update UI

Tags: android, handler

I have a small project to test update UI and OnItemClickListener.

When I update ui. OnItemClickListener sometimes not trigger.
If I update ui more often, OnItemClickListener lose more times.

```
mHadler = new Handler();
mHanler.postDelayed(this, 33); // update 33 times per second.
// mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // update 1 times per second.
                                     // never lose onItemClick event.
```

my Runable

```
@Override
public void run() {
    mText.setText("100");
    mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_icon);
    mList.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mList2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    ....
}
```

my OnItemClickListener

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
    // do something...
    // not trigger sometimes.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be aware of running code on the MainThread (aka - the UI thread in Android). There are serious memory implications to updating your GUI 33 times per second.

Research:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/05/painless-threading.html